# JQuery - Access children by ID from Raw HTML

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery, so this may be a stupid question, however I have not been able to find a solution.

I have a raw HTML string stored as a JS variable, as shown below.  What I would like to do is parse the HTML string as a DOM object, and be able to access and change any children within the div by their id.

So, I would need to access "ht" and "vt" by id after the raw HTML is parsed.  How would I perform this?

```
var htmlStr = "<div><span id='ht'>test 1</span><span id='vt'>test 2</span></div>";
$(htmlStr).ht // Something like this, that would return "test 1"
```

I am basically trying to use some raw HTML as a template for creating items in an unordered list.  I would create the new list item using the template, and then replace certain portions of the template with data from a web service.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example, you could do.

```
var htmlStr = "<div><span id='ht'>test 1</span><span id='vt'>test 2</span></div>";
var htContent = $('#ht', htmlStr).text();
```

Basically, you are getting an element with the ID of `ht`, from within the context of the `<div>` stored in your `htmlStr` variable.

Then, you are retrieving its text content with `.text()`. Alternatively, you could retrieve any html tags as well with `.html()`.

---

**EDIT:**

If you are going to do much work with that html string, you can store it in a jQuery object, and do whatever you want, even though it hasn't yet been inserted into the DOM

```
var $htmlStr = $("<div><span id='ht'>test 1</span><span id='vt'>test 2</span></div>");
```

Now `$htmlStr` is a jQuery object, and you can manipulate it with the multitude of jQuery methods.

Comment: $('#ht', htmlStr).text() should be replace with $(htmlStr).find('#ht'). Since jQuery internally will do the exact same it's just one function call overhead with a terrible readability.

Comment: Readability is in the eye of the beholder. :o)

Comment: @jAndy: I don't understand your point. How does mine suffer a performance loss?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#ht",htmlStr).html()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var htmlStr = "<div><span id='ht'>test 1</span><span id='vt'>test 2</span></div>";
$(htmlStr).find('#ht').text();
```

should do it.